# Parse large and multiple fetches for statistics

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, statistics, fetch

In my app I want to retrieve a large amount of data from Parse to build a view of statistics. However, in future, as data builds up, this may be a huge amount.

For example, 10,000 results. Even if I fetched in batches of 1000 at a time, this would result in 10 fetches. This could rapidly, send me over the 30 requests per second limitation by Parse. Specifically when several other chunks of data may need to be collected at the same time for other stats.

Any recommendations/tips/advice for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You will also run into limits with the `skip` and `limit` query variables. And heavy weight lifting on a mobile device could also present issues for you.

If you can you should pre-aggregate these statistics, perhaps once per day, so that you can simply directly request the details.

Alternatively, create a cloud code function to do some processing for you and return the results. Again, you may well run into limits here, so a cloud job may meed your needs better, and then you may need to effectively create a request object which is processed by the job and then poll for completion or send out push notifications on completion.

Comment: Interesting. But running cloud code, would that not also use up requests in the same way that calling them directly in app would?

Comment: It would, yes, and you'd probably actually use `.each` which would run batches of 100. Hence the preprocessing suggestion if you can... Either that or choose a different server.